# VueJS : Add a tooltip component on legacy HTML base on class selector?

Tags: vue.js, tippyjs

I would like to add VueTippy (the vue wrapper for Tippy.js) to text (HTML, stored in DB) which has a format like this :

```
My <a href="/slug/" class="mySelector">Text</a> around.
```

I would like that when hovered I can display a tooltip for this link (dynamic, depending of link). And as this tooltip will have button & actions I would like to have a VueJS component.

But how can add my vue component to a simple link ?
Thanks

Comment: please share more code

Comment: Which code ?

I don't know how to do it, so I tried some idea but nothing work.